# How do we classify Cookies in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, cookies, cookiebot

How do we know number of cookies we are using and classify them?
Like Necessary, Statistics, Preference and Marketing and number of cookies in overall websites

In the image added below it is showing cookies count in each classification.

How we can get count of cookies?

There is a laravel package using cookiebot [github](https://github.com/digifactory/laravel-cookie-consent)

I am not sure in this package cookie count is passed.

[image: cookiebot]